# Как добавить нули в пустые строки таблицы чтобы вывести все значения одной строкой?

Tags: javascript

Пробую достать данные из 2 столбца таблицы, вроде бы получается, единственное это не могу додумать как вместо пустых ячеек добавить ноль. И вывести все полученные значения в одну строку (пример 012002)

```js
var razArray = document.getElementsByClassName("chenge");

for(var i=0;razArray.length>i;i++){
  var currentContent = razArray[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(currentContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
 
 <tr>
 <td>День недели</td>
 <td>Значение</td>
 <tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">2</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Понедельник</td>
  <td class="chenge " data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Вторник</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Среда</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Четверг</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1">1</td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Пятница</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Суббота</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Воскресенье</td>
  <td class="chenge" data-name="mmessage1"></td>
 <tr>
 
 
</table>
```

Comment: `razArray.map(el => (el.innerText || 0)).join('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery
arr = [];

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
   arr.push($(this).find('td:last-child').text());
})

console.log(arr)
```

в одну строку arr.join()

Обновлено

```
arr = [];
$('table tr').each(function(i) {

if(i > 0) {
   var str = $(this).find('td:last-child').text();
   str = parseInt(str) ? str : 0 ;
   $(this).find('td:last-child').text(str)
   arr.push(str);
 }

})

console.log(arr.join(''))
```

Comment: Пустые строки нужно превратить в нули

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: этот код учитывает заголовок 2 столбца и пишет в начале 0 а не должен

Comment: тогда замените str = parseInt(str) ? str : 0; на str = str ? str : 0 ;

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, только сегодня заметил. А почему нули добавляются между цифрами где не должны быть. Например в таблице идут дни друг за другом где  стоят 111 а ваш код вставляет между ними нули 10101 и т.д. это ведь не правильно ?

Comment: Это потому, что у вас теги tr не закрытые, браузер их автоматом закрывает, но создаёт пустой tr. То есть у вас <tr><td></td><td></td><tr> видит как <tr><td></td></td></tr><tr></tr>. Закройте теги <tr>

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, этот серьезный недочет поправил, спасибо. При выводе пишет теперь Значение011120012220000111000 (как избавится от заголовка столбца ?), строку эту оставил так str = str ? str : 0 ; как и сказали.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52914/discussion-between--and-konstantin-okhotnick).

Comment: Обновил  пример.